# Dialogflow when added firestore code, makes webhook call fails

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, dialogflow-es

I am making a chatbot with dialogflow on NodeJS and need to integrate firestore.
I have followed various tutorials, tried many ways (other than Attempt 1 and Attempt 2), but none would work.
In the `getStaffProfile(agent)` function, the first 3 line would work when their is only the 3 lines, the fulfillment status show `Webhook execution successful`

After adding the code where it calls the db(Attempt ! or Attempt 2), I have tried using `firebase deploy` and `npm run deploy` to deploy the new changes, the fulfillment status became `Webhook call failed. Error: UNAVAILABLE.`

So I figured something must be wrong with the firebase/firestore side, so I tried `firebase deploy`, `firebase init`, and `npm run deploy` again and again and again with minor changes in the attempts to get data from the firestore, and then I got `Webhook call failed. Error: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED.`

Something I should mention that is when I download the codes from inline editor, I did not get a `firebase.json` file like the tutorials I followed so I created it myself with `{}` as the sole content in the json file

I have no idea whats wrong now, can anybody help me please?
Here is the code of both files I am using

My index.js file

```
'use strict';
     
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
    const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
     
    const admin = require('firebase-admin');
    admin.initializeApp();
    
    const db = admin.firestore();
    
    process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements
     
    exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
      const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
      console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
      console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

    
      function getStaffProfile(agent){
        agent.add('getStaffProfile VSCode')
        let staffName= agent.parameters['staffName'];
        agent.add(`Here you go, from VS Code ${staffName}`)

        //Attempt 1: Didn't work
        const staffRef = db.collection('staffs');
        return db.collection('staffs').doc(staffName).get()
          .then( doc => {
            var value = doc.data();
            agent.add(`The population of ${staffName} is ${value.staff_id}.`);
          });
    
        //Attempt 2: Didnt work
        //const staffDoc = db.collection('staffs').doc('staffNameKey');
        //return staffDoc.get()
        //  .then(doc => {
        //    if (!doc.exists) {
        //      agent.add('No data found in the database!');
        //    } else {
        //      agent.add(doc.data().staffTitle);
        //    }
        //    return Promise.resolve('Read complete');
        //  }).catch(() => {
        //    agent.add('Error reading entry from the Firestore database.');
        //    agent.add('Please add a entry to the database first by saying, "Write <your phrase> to the database"');
        //  });
      }
    
    
    
      // Run the proper function handler based on the matched Dialogflow intent name
      let intentMap = new Map();
      intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
      intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
      intentMap.set('getStaffProfile', getStaffProfile);
      intentMap.set('getYTable', getYTable);
      intentMap.set('courseSelection', courseSelection);
      // intentMap.set('your intent name here', yourFunctionHandler);
      // intentMap.set('your intent name here', googleAssistantHandler);
      agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
    });
```

My package.json
{

```
  "name": "dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
  "description": "This is the default fulfillment for a Dialogflow agents using Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "license": "Apache Version 2.0",
  "author": "Google Inc.",
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "firebase serve --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment --project charlie-alpha-pjlvfm"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "actions-on-google": "^2.2.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^5.13.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.0.2",
    "dialogflow": "^0.6.0",
    "dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.5.0",
    "@google-cloud/firestore": "^0.16.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You report that the attempts "don't work" and that it looks like you're getting deadline exceeded in the response. Do you have any logs from the Firebase Cloud Function? Are you even running this as a Cloud Function? The more information you can provide, the better our chances of helping you.

Comment: I install Google Cloud SDK and set current project as this project, is that running as cloud function?;  firebase log it shows
dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment
Error: Argument "documentPath" is not a valid ResourcePath. Path must be a non-empty string. at Object.exports.(anonymous function) [as isResourcePath] (/srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/validate.js:89:23) at CollectionReference.doc (/srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:1813:22) at getStaffProfile (/srv/index.js:45:36) at ...

Comment: Please update your original question with any additional information, and then post a comment that you've done so. This makes it much easier to read and keeps the entire question in one place.